# Set a dynamic property in the class constructor

Tags: php, pdo

```
class QuestionVO {

public $qtype;

function __construct() { //echo $this->qtype; //it's not empty and displays value
    $this->{$this->qtype} = true;
}
```

pdo statement

```
$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_class(new QuestionVO()));
```

it's throwing fatal error.

however, the document says at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059 
"This fetch method allows you to fetch data directly into a class of your choosing. When you use FETCH_CLASS, the properties of your object are set BEFORE the constructor is called. "

```
Fatal error</b>:  Cannot access empty property in QuestionVO
```

for instance if $qtype = truefalse

I need a dynamic property set automatically as truefalse = true for the object.

Comment: Set value for `$this->qtype` first.

Comment: Well `$qtype` never will be `"truefalse"`, will it? It's defaulted to `null`, probably. Is this class inherited somewhere that sets `$qtype`?

Comment: I've edited my question, the properties are being set by PDO before constructor is called\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that PDO will populate the object before calling the constructor. But when you simply call `new QuestionVO`, it doesn't populate the object.

So it won't work to use `get_class(new QuestionVO())`, and you don't need to do that anyway.  Just name the class, like this:

```
$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'QuestionVO');
```

But what happens if the value of `qtype` in the query's result set is null? Then you're back to the same problem.

You should code your constructor to not assume `qtype` is set:

```
function __construct() {
    if (isset($this->qtype)) {
        $this->{$this->qtype} = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have following code

```
$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_class(new QuestionVO()));
```

Here, `get_class(new QuestionVO())` you passed an object to the `get_class` method as an argument so, think it this way:

```
$obj = new QuestionVO(); // <-- error is rising at this point of initialization
get_class($obj);
```

So, it's not `PDO` but you are trying to make an instance of that class manually before `PDO` set the properties to this class/object and until `PDO` set properties, it's an empty property.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps with an additional variable:

```
class QuestionVO {

    public $qtype;

    function __construct() {
        $methodname = $this->qtype;
        $this->$methodname = true;
}
```

Obviously, `$methodname` must already be populated, so maybe it's better if you pass it in the constructor:

```
class QuestionVO {

    public $qtype;

    function __construct($methodname) {
        $this->qtype = $methodname;
        $this->$methodname = true;
}
```

Comment: what if properties are being set by PDO, I've revised the question

Comment: Then it should be ok, because `PDO` populates your instance *BEFORE* the constructor is called. Try *first* the first snippet and only then the other if it didn't help.

Comment: Also: just try to do a var_dump(this) inside the constructor before and after you set the dynamic property.

Comment: same error, Cannot access empty property in (I can't pass in the constructor because it's called by PDO)

Comment: tried var_dump($this), it displays NULL for all properties, however, echo $this->qtype displays a valid value

Comment: I guess you've already found this and it didn't help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850844/add-attribute-to-an-object-in-php

Comment: the above link talks about properties in general, however, this problem is in context of PDO, I read. "When fetching an object, the constructor of the class is called after the fields are populated by default", however, this is not the case in here or something